# Count and limit the number of files uploaded using VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, image-uploading, sql-server-2014

I want to take input of 5 images from user, show thumbnails and save them to 5 columns in SQL-database(image1,image2,image3,image4,image5).

Please add code for sql insertion of these 5 files.

Please help me out

```
   Private Sub BrowseMultipleFilesButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BrowseMultipleFilesButton.Click
    Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter =
     "Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF,*.PNG,*.TIFF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.TIFF|" +
     "All files (*.*)|*.*"

    OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = True
    Dim index As New Integer

    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select Photos"

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        For Each file As String In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
            Dim imageControl As New PictureBox()
            imageControl.Height = 100
            imageControl.Width = 100
            Dim myCallback As New Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(AddressOf ThumbnailCallback)
            Dim myBitmap As New Bitmap(file)
            Dim myThumbnail As Image = myBitmap.GetThumbnailImage(96, 96, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero)
            imageControl.Image = myThumbnail

            PhotoGallary.Controls.Add(imageControl)
            index = OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex()
        Next
        If index > 5 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select no more than 5 files")
        Else
            btn_Save.Enabled = True

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: problem is, code is not restricting me to upload more than 5 files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to allow 5 image files, there is no need to bother making thumbnails before testing the number of files. Since [FileDialog.FileNames Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an array of strings, the first thing you want to do after testing that the `DialogResult` is Ok, is test the length of the array:

```
If OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Length > 5 Then 
    MessageBox.Show("Please select no more than 5 files")
    Exit sub
End If
'' The rest of your code, including the row btn_Save.Enabled = True.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...it works!  but I have to show images which upload by user

Comment: also tell me how to save these 5 images in sql-database 5 columns

Comment: I thought your question was how to restrict the number of images. Saving them to sql server is another subject all together, you can probably find good solutions on google for that.

Comment: yeh! its doing but if I insert more 5 images it shows 10 images in galley....andwe can only take 5 images to save

Comment: add `PhotoGallary.Controls.Clear()` to the method that saves the images. this will remove all images from the Gallary after each save.

Comment: Glad to help :-) Please mark this answer as accepted so that other people will know this problem is solved. If you have any more issues, don't hesitate to post new questions. btw, peled is my last name.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!

```
Private Sub BrowseMultipleFilesButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BrowseMultipleFilesButton.Click
    Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter =
     "Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF,*.PNG,*.TIFF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.TIFF|" +
     "All files (*.*)|*.*"

    OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = True
    Dim index As New Integer

    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select Photos"

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        If OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Length > 5 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select no more than 5 files")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Length < 5 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select 5 files")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        For Each file As String In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
            Dim imageControl As New PictureBox()
            imageControl.Height = 100
            imageControl.Width = 100
            Dim myCallback As New Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(AddressOf ThumbnailCallback)
            Dim myBitmap As New Bitmap(file)
            Dim myThumbnail As Image = myBitmap.GetThumbnailImage(96, 96, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero)
            imageControl.Image = myThumbnail

            PhotoGallary.Controls.Add(imageControl)
            index = OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex()
        Next
        btn_Save.Enabled = True
        BrowseMultipleFilesButton.Enabled = False


    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just check if the length is different then 5 in one condition?

Comment: Yeh! we can also do that.